# How to call an Protected API from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-identity

There is an Azure Web App service and I have to call an API get method on that service. The web app service is under Identity Provider protection and the **caller has to be an Azure function**.

I have gotten the following message Azure function has started to work: **"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."** That message has sent from Azure Web App (protected by Azure identity provider)

As you guys can realize, the Azure function does not have permission to call the protected Azure Web App service. The reason is clear for me, the web app service is protected by Azure Identity Provider.

How can I call the **get method** on Web App service from the Azure function in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I understand that this should work is that you have to **enable managed identity** on your Azure Function. This will create a managed Application (Service Principal) inside your Azure Active Directory.

Then you will have to **grant** this managed application **permission** to invoke your Azure Web App.
In your Azure Function, you will have to add some implementation to **acquire a token** for your Azure Web App using the managed identity you have created earlier. With the token, you can create a REST request that contains the access token for your API.

Here is a [code example for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#net-example)

Comment: Hello Martin, Thnak you for helping me. I have already gotten the token. My next step is to invoke the protected API. I have gotten the message: "Unauthorized"

Comment: I have tried out the following code but I have gotten unauthorized: var client = new RestClient({url});
            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Method = Method.Get;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var response = client.Execute(request);

Comment: go to jwt.io and pass the content of the access token there. Then check the audiance and issuer claim and compare with the configuration you are using within your API

Comment: Thank you Martin. This issue has solved. The Microsoft Identity has workd well!

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to use Managed Identities

You give your Azure function a System-assigned Identity.

And then you grant rights to that System-assigned Identity on your Azure Web App.

See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Chttp

Comment: Hello Shiraz I'm going to try this solution. I will keep you informed when get it ready.

Comment: Hello Shiraz, I have gotten the token finally. My next step is to find a way to invoke the protected API. Thank you!!